# PHP DateTime 12 hours and 55 minutes off?

Tags: php, datetime

Can someone please help me figure out my mistake here?

```
<?php
$date_clockstart = new DateTime('2019-04-21');
$date_clockstart->setTime(23, 59, 59);
echo $date_clockstart->format("Y-m-d h:m:s");
?>
```

Expected: `2019-04-21 23:59:59` but I keep getting: `2019-04-21 11:04:59`

Changing `date_default_timezone_set()` has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time format string is wrong.
See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

The m in `h:m:s` is months. You want to use `i` for minutes and capital `H` for 24 hour hours.

Try:

```
echo $date_clockstart->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

use **H:i:s** instead of **h:m:s**

```
$date_clockstart->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the wrong format.

Try this instead of your echo

```
echo $date_clockstart->format("Y/m/d H:i:s");
```